# Describing the contents of a column containing chronological numbers in the table

Tags: phrase-request

A teacher has a table of students in his class:

```
#  Name
1  Jenny
2  Henry
3  George
4  William
5  Billy
```

Some new students are still being added to his class, so he appends some new names to his table almost every lesson.

I know how to describe the second row of the table - simply "Column 2: Students' names"

However, I am not quite sure how to describe the first column.

Here is my try:

> Column 1: Chronological numbers of students, according to the sequence
>   of how they were met by the teacher.

Sounds very broken. How would a native English speaker describe the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch a movie, sometimes the credits will list the actors **in order of appearance**.

The word **appearance** is not apt for your classroom scenario, but the phrase **in order of** fits.

So, **in order of** {whatever matches your real-world scenario}.  Arrival? Sign-up?

> The numbers in column #1 show each student's position in order of arrival.

P.S. I take it that you're not looking for a label for a database column but a descriptive phrase in natural, idiomatic English.

If the column were a date-time:

> The date-time values in column #1 show when each student arrived (or when the teacher met the student for the first time).

Answer (score 3):

Column 1: Order of students' arrival (to the class)

Answer (score -1):

> Column 1 is the number of students
>   Column 2 is the name of the students

then for Column 3, you could use

> Column 3 is the order in which the teacher met each student

this is assuming 1 is the first student the teacher met...

Comment: Why create column 3 when column 1 is already exactly that? Can I say like this: "Column 1 - numbers of students in the order, in which the teacher met each student"?

Comment: @brilliant You are correct if you assume the teacher met the students in that order which usually would not be the case (the probability would be very small).

Comment: Why would the probability be very small if the teacher himself was filling up this table as he met the students? Did you read these words in my question: "he appends some new names to his table almost every lesson"?

Comment: @brilliant If the teacher is adding the name s **as** he meets them, then you are correct, and you can use my description of Column 3 for Column 1

Comment: "If the teacher is adding the names as he meets them" - which has been the case since the moment this question was posted here :)